# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Im trying to input multiple requests to one session, the idea is to log http traffic with mitmproxy but im still constructing the database, im sure there is something bad in my models but i cannot find what

The idea is to Store multiple requests in one session, accesing easily to each requests response if needed.

db.py

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

schema_name = 'Traffic'

engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxx:xxx@localhost:5432/xxx')

if not engine.dialect.has_schema(engine, schema_name):
    engine.execute(sqlalchemy.schema.CreateSchema(schema_name))

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
```

Request.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from entities.utils import db
from entities.utils.utils import _repr

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, JSON, INTEGER, ForeignKey, Integer, DateTime


class RequestModel(db.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'requests'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    headers = Column(JSON,nullable=False)
    method = Column(String,nullable=False)
    size = Column(INTEGER,nullable=False)
    timestamp_end = Column(DateTime,nullable=False)
    timestamp_start = Column(DateTime,nullable=False)
    status_code = Column(INTEGER,nullable=False)
    body = Column(JSON,nullable=True)
    url = Column(String,nullable=False)



    response_id =  Column(INTEGER,ForeignKey('responses.id'))


    def __init__(self,method,status_code,url):
        self.method = method
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.url = url
```

Session.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from entities.utils import db
from entities.utils import utils

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey


class SessionModel(db.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sessions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    server = Column(String, nullable=False)
    world = Column(String,nullable=False)
    user = Column(String,nullable=False)
    version = Column(String,nullable=False)
    requests_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('requests.id'))
    requests = relationship('RequestModel')



    def __init__(self,server,world,user,version):
        self.server = server
        self.world = world
        self.user = user
        self.version = version



    def __repr__(self):
        return self._repr(id=self.id,server=self.server,
                          world=self.world,user=self.user,version=self.version)
```

Response.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base
from entities.utils import db
from entities.utils.utils import _repr

from sqlalchemy import Column, JSON, INTEGER, ForeignKey, Integer


class ResponseModel(db.Base):

    __tablename__ = 'responses'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    headers = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    status_code = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)
    body = Column(JSON, nullable=True)


    def __init__(self, headers, status_code, body):
        self.headers = headers
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.body = body

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._repr(id=self.id, status=self.status_code)
```

Input.py

```
import json
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import datetime
from entities.models.Request import RequestModel
from entities.models.Response import ResponseModel
from entities.models.Session import SessionModel





engine = create_engine('postgresql://XXX:XXX@localhost:5423/XXXX')
Base = declarative_base()
# create session and add objects
with Session(engine) as session:
    response_object = ResponseModel(body={'22':'22'},status_code=402,headers={'test':'test'})
    session.add(response_object)
    session.commit()

    object_1 = RequestModel('POST', 402, 'www.intersecting.com/url?=parameter1&key')
    object_1.headers = {'test':'19'}
    object_1.body = {'test':'19'}
    object_1.size = 512
    object_1.timestamp_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    object_1.timestamp_end =datetime.datetime.now()
    object_2 = object_1
    session.add(object_1)
    session.commit()
    session_object = SessionModel('www.test.com','test62','admin','3.12.13')
    print(session_object)
    session_object.requests = {object_2,object_1}
    session.add(session_object)
    session.commit()
```

But im not able to store 2 requests in one session i get this error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/qwert/PycharmProjects/Tribalwars/entities/utils/examples/input.py", line 35, in <module>
    session.add(session_object)
  File "C:\Users\qwert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2573, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "C:\Users\qwert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2589, in _save_or_update_state
    for o, m, st_, dct_ in mapper.cascade_iterator(
  File "C:\Users\qwert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3166, in cascade_iterator
    queue = deque(
  File "C:\Users\qwert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1982, in cascade_iterator
    tuples = state.manager[self.key].impl.get_all_pending(state, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\qwert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1169, in get_all_pending
    ret = [(instance_state(current), current)]
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Comment: You should add a list to `session_object.requests` and not a dict.

Comment: no, i already tried that and gets me to the same
    session_object.requests = [object_2,object_1]
gives me error 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Comment: What happens if you do `session_object.requests.append([object_2, object_1])`?